# How to make ul in left side of the page in nextjs tailwindcss?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

How to make ul in left side of the page in nextjs tailwindcss? i tried adding a margin right to it but its not working how can I make left side of the page

```
    <section class="px-4 lg:px-20 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <h1 class="font-sans font-bold text-4xl md:text-5xl lg:text-4xl leading-loose text-white-800  mt-20">Website</h1>
        <div class="text-white-800 mt-20">
            <h1 className='font-sans font-bold text-4xl md:text-5xl lg:text-4xl leading-loose text-white-800 mb-6'>Nextjs</h1>
            <ul class="list-disc mr-24 text-left">
                <li>First bullet point</li>
                <li>Second bullet point</li>
                <li>Third bullet point</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: add w-full to the div element no need to the margin in the ul

Comment: @mmh4all this works but how to add dots to bullet points

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `justify-center items-center` in the `section` element.